# How does std::cout work with char pointers?

Tags: c++, pointers, char

Recently I've been learning about C++ pointers and I'm confused when it comes to char.

`char *c = "sampletext";`

`cout<< *c <<endl;`

`cout<< c <<endl;`

`cout<< &c <<endl;`

To be more precise: why does `cout<< c <<endl;` print whole C-string instead of address (as it takes place in int pointers for example),
and why does `cout<< *c <<endl;` print first letter instead of whole C-string. Thank you in advance

Comment: Rule of thumb: always expect `char*` to be treated differently than any other pointer type. That's from C, where text is represented as nul-terminated char arrays, so everything that deals with text actually traffics in `char*` (or `const char*`, of course). So, naturally, things go the other way, too: just about every `char*` is assumed to point at a nul-terminated array of `char`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because the compiler checks the type of the argument and calls the overloaded version of the operator that receives that type.

In the C language, strings are implemented as `char` arrays terminated with the `’\0’` (nul) character, and arrays are referred to using pointers. So, when the argument received is `c`, the overloaded operator that receives a `char*` prints the content of the array up to the nul terminator.

When the argument received is `*c`, this dereferences the pointer to access its data, and since this is a pointer to `char`, the overloaded operator that receives a `char` prints it as a single `char`.

To print the address of the string array, you can cast the `char*` pointer to `void*`, like follows:

```
std::cout << (void*) c << std::endl;
```